# Which Image format is recommended/ best for geoserver raster wms services?

Tags: geoserver, wms, geotiff-tiff, mbtiles, mrsid

I have very high resolution image of vast area(true color RGB bands). I am planning to to reduce the image size by reducing it to 16 bits (or less). which image format is best for performance point of view. finally to narrow down more my question shall i use mbtiles or tiff or mrsid or any other format/ method you like to suggest ?

Comment: Have you read the raster sections of the GeoServer on steroids presentation http://www.slideshare.net/geosolutions/gs-steroids-foss4ge2014?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best Format is mbtiles . I used tilemill to make mbtiles (note tile mill only accepts 3857) The final size of image was 16 GB . Using Tile server it was very easy to make WMTS out of it . Which was almost 20 times faster than geoserver wms . (note geoserver is ImageMosaic ,GeoTIFF are ok when the image size is less than 2 GB)

Answer (score 2):

What ever the format, the raster tiles can be loaded faster using the GeoWebCache,
where all the tiles has been pre generated and the tiles can be loaded directly without generating it for each request.

> GeoWebCache is integrated with geoserver no additional component is required.

check out this link [GeoWebCache](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/geowebcache/using.html) for integrating this with geoserver

> The most preferable format is **geotiff**

Comment: i will be using geowebcache by default. can you state reason why geotiff is preferable ? as if I use mrsid i will save lots of space as compared to geotiff . so will it make difference if i use mrsid rather than geotiff ?

Comment: GeoTIFF with JPEG compression is no bigger than MrSID but if you will finally use tiles then just use whatever you want as originals. When you seeded the cache you can even remove the originals from your server.

Comment: Rather than format the memory is mainly depends on the number of zoom levels or resolutions you used in the application and by selecting suitable tile size for your application.